# What would be an instance where MultiStatement Table Valued Function(MTVF) is needed over an Inline Table Valued Function(ITVF) in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2014, table-valued-parameters

I was able to write two SQL queries, first one is an Inline Table Valued Function(ITVF) and the latter is a Multistatement Table Valued Function(MTVF) for the same task which is quering the worktime of certain employees.

-------------- Inline Table Valued Function (ITVF) ---------------------

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION fn_ITVF_GetWorkTimes()
> RETURNS TABLE
> AS RETURN( SELECT E.ID, E.Name, E.DepartmentID, R.TotalTime
>          FROM tblEmployee E
>          INNER JOIN
>          ( SELECT T.Id, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartTime,EndTime)/60.0 as DECIMAL(18,2)) AS 'TotalTime'
>            FROM tblTimeRecord T) AS R
>          ON E.ID = R.Id )
>
> SELECT * FROM fn_ITVF_GetWorkTimes();
> ```

---------------  Multi-Statement Table Valued Functions (MTVF) -------------------

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION fn_MTVF_GetEmployeeTimes()
> RETURNS @Table1 TABLE(Id INT,Name NVARCHAR(50),DepartmentID INT,TimeWork DECIMAL(18,2))
> AS
> BEGIN    
>     INSERT INTO @Table1
>     SELECT E.Id, E.Name, E.DepartmentId, R.TotalTime
>     FROM tblEmployee AS E
>     INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT T.ID, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,T.StartTime,T.EndTime)/60.0 as DECIMAL (18,2)) AS 'TotalTime'
>     FROM tblTimeRecord AS T) AS R
>     ON E.Id=R.ID
>     RETURN
> END
>
> SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_MTVF_GetEmployeeTimes();
> ```

I am aware that few questions have been raised on this topic earlier, but still i could not find out a scenario which only a MultiStatement Table Valued Function can be applied and is there a clear reason why an ITVF cannot be applied for such a scenario ? According to my research it has been advised to use ITVF all the time if it is possible and it seems it is more efficient than MTVF as well. If it is true why would anyone tend to use MTVF ? Clear explantion with examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your logic is too complicated to put into one query in ITVF, then there is no other choice, but use MTVF. If you can rewrite the logic to fit into ITVF, then most likely it would be more efficient than MTVF, but it is not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the syntax the main limitation between IVTF and MVTF is that IVTF can only have `A Single Select Statement` same as views.

Whereas on the other hand MVTF can have a more complex logic inside them. IF/Else blocks etc.

Some say IVTF can be seen as Parameterised Views and MVTF can be seen as Stored procedures you can select from.